# Speed up videos using ffmpeg without setpts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Is there any way to speed up videos in ffmpeg but have it actually remove frames instead of just speeding up the time the frame is shown? The reason I want to do this is because I wanted a way to speed up videos without re-encoding. Also I'm aiming to speed it up to 4500x which renders the video almost unplayable when using setpts. Is this possible?

Comment: like this? https://superuser.com/questions/1172420/ffmpeg-resampling-240-fps-video-down-to-30-fps

Comment: @Jasen
Is there any way to do this without extracting all the frames first?

Comment: You can only drop frames without re-encoding if your stream is intra-coded or at the least all the frames you want to keep are intra-coded. Why is setpts with 4500x unplayable - what's your command?